How to make google chat bot send direct messages to user?
There is the following case: there is a Google chatbot, it works in space. The message handler is located in Cloud Functions and runs on node.js .
Task: when sending a certain message in space, I need to make the bot to send some message to certain users directly.
While investigating the task, I discovered that the bot cannot send messages to users directly. So I want to create a private space between chat bot and the user. Then I discovered that to create a Space, there is an oAuth2 authorization as a User needed (service-account auth not working): https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/authenticate-authorize-chat-user
I followed the steps from documentation, but I couldn't authorize. Question: is it possible in principle to authorize a Google chatbot as a user?
If not, how can I send a private (visible only) message to space to several users at once? Example of sending to one user from the documentation:
res.json({
text: "Hello private world!",
privateMessageViewer: {
name:  "users/USER_ID"
}
});
But this method only sends a message to one user. An attempt to pass an array of objects results in the error: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Headers cannot be set after they are sent to the client on ServerResponse.setHeader
I will be grateful for the answers

The question is closed. The security policy of Google forbids chat bots to create Spaces with users as well as authorize as a User (only service-account auth can be established). To start interacting with chat bot users need to manually create the Space.
In my case there are 2 alternative solutions:

Asynchronously send emails with certain message to needed users
To iterate users dataset and send "visible only" messages in Space using
res.json({ text: "Message text", privateMessageViewer: { name: // iterated user id } });

